# Reuse Nodejs Api

Tags: node.js

I have a written an api in nodejs to find list of leads or customers. Now i have to use this api from another controller. How to pass query paramters from another controller and get list of leads from it. Hence will be able to reuse code.

```
exports.listofLeads = function (req, res) {

  var param = req.query.from;   var s = "initialSource";   var queryLeads = Customers.find({"attributes": { $size: 0 }} ,{"email":1});   if(! param) {
    queryLeads.exec(function (err, articles) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
      } else {
        res.json(articles);
      }
    });   } else {
    queryLeads.and([ { [s]: param } ]).exec(function (err, articles) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
      } else {
        res.json(articles);
      }
    });   
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using require() you can access file in which you have written this function. So in other api just call this function and pass parameters as you did in first api

Comment: Using require(), i am able to access the function "listofleads", but `var param = req.query.from;` throws error. My code in another controller is `var customers = require('../controllers/customers.server.controller');


exports.list = function (req, res) {
 var from = req.query.from;
 console.log(from);
 var x = customers.listofLeads(from);
 console.log(x);
};`

Comment: This error occured because listofleads api accepts  `var param = req.query.from;` but when accessing via another controller it expects to get only `var param = req;`. How to make it modular so that it can be used both as an api as well as from within the controller.

Comment: to make it modular in exports.listofLeads = function (req, res) {} as one more parameter say flag like exports.listofLeads = function (req, res,flag) {}

Comment: so while calling it from api 1 pass flag=1 and while calling from api 2 pass flag=2 so in common function you can use if(flag==1){ var param = req.query.from; }else {  var param = req;}

Comment: after response if i pass any thing like flag. nodejs is taking it as next(). i did a console.log(flag); it returned `[Function: next]
`

Comment: first parameter is req then res then next. there is no scope to pass flag parameter.

Comment: in that case you can check length of req.query if its having "from" in parameter it will greater than 0 else it will be 0 . So you can write param variable in if else loop

Comment: To up vote you must click on the triangle over the 0 in the answer (top left corner).